# How multiple canvas elements affect performance?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a simple game (view from above) on canvas. Please tell me, which is faster:

1) Draw everything on one `<canvas>` and calculate the areas that need to be redrawn.

2) Draw certain parts of the scene on different `<canvas>` elements and update each only if necessary. In the it variant, probably, I can also use a partial redraw.

For example, I could draw a map on one element, enemies on the second, and a cursor and etc on the third. When moving enemies, I could only redraw the second canvas.

Please explain in as much detail as possible which option is better and why. And could you please advise books that can deepen my knowledge on this issue? For beginners.

Comment: As is your question is unanswerable as it will depend on what the code has to do. Complexity only makes work for the CPU. Keep it simple for performance.  Most games will use one display canvas and redraw that whole canvas every frame (1/60sec). Best way to knowledge is to do, so open up an IDE and start writing code and you will soon have your question answered. BTW tracking redraw areas is a dead end.

Comment: Why do you think that tracking redraw areas is a dead end? I thought this should reduce the load

Comment: Its all about PPS (pixels per second) GPU is fast, javascript not. To see what I mean, create a canvas and get the context then run `const test = s => {
    var n = performance.now();
    for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i ++){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,s,s);
    }  console.log( ((performance.now() - n) / (s*s)) );}
test(10);
test(300);` the second call clears pixels ~10,000 times quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Most canvas games will use a sort of layering that you are describing. The furthest forward layer would be the HUD, either by a seperate canvas or HTML elements and this would only change if something happened to it, such as someone upgrading their player. Then after that it depends on how they draw the canvas. The simplest way would be to simply draw the portions of the map and obstacles are on the screen.

Comment: You do realise that layering one canvas on top of another still requires compositing once a frame, if write pixels to any layer during that frame. That it is actually slower to have the DOM handle (badly) the compositing than doing it (well) via drawImage in javascript, because that way you can take some short cuts that the DOM will not be aware of.

Comment: Well the whole point of it is to not redraw as frequently as the game canvas, only onChange.

Comment: If you modify a single pixel on any of the layered all the layers must be composited. With a background and a foreground layered canvas. You will need to clear the foreground to draw on it. When you exit, the DOM will recomp the background and foreground canvases. But if you keep the background offscreen and use it to clear `ctx.drawImage(bgCanvas,0,0)` rather than use `ctx.clearRect` you save a whole screen's worth of pixel writes. layered canvases don't magically composite themselves, they require the GPU just like a drawImage call. What's slower than JS?? the DOM

Answer (score -1):

Use one canvas, trust me. If you have a sprite that does nothing but sit there it is still getting drawn 60 times a second so it makes no difference if it is moving or not changing or not if it exists on screen it is getting drawn regardless of change.