# Is it better to stack multiple canvases in DOM or control all drawing in one canvases?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have been involved in projects in the past which have involved layering canvases.
I have worked with people who stand by layering canvases, but I have strong doubts as to whether this is the best method.

The main questions I have are:

If canvases are layered and one of them changes, then all of them will be repainted by the browser in order for them to appear. However, this will avoid any update/paint functions to the canvas, or calculating pixels on it.

Is dom handling compositing slow? If there are layers that are created through multiple draw calls, such as a complicated background constructed of sprites, would rendering them to an offscreen canvas and draw that canvas to the main one using draw image?

If you are layering canvases and they all need to draw at some points, wouldn't the performance drop significantly, since you're doubling the number of pixels to calculate? I have found in games that I worked on that lowering the size of the canvas increases performance significantly, and I try to go no higher than needed.

Specifically, the comments on this posts by user: Blindman67 have given me doubts about layering multiple canvases.

[How multiple canvas elements affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46651501/how-multiple-canvas-elements-affect-performance)

Does anyone have any experience with both methods and knows which tends to perform better? Is the browser slow?

Comment: It all depends on what you are doing

Comment: Okay, but you literally have an answer in the comments of the question you linked?

Comment: @zfrisch there's not a lot to go on there, and I would like to learn more. Would PM the guy, but that's not a thing.

Comment: Right, but the answer really is that it depends. Each specific use case is different. Certainly using more canvases equates to more rendering of canvas elements, which is more work - unless those Canvases are used to mitigate re-rendering that would be happening otherwise. It also allows for simple compartmentalization of things like separate framerates and the code base in general. There are a lot of variables, it's not cut and dry.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you're doing. If you're drawing a bunch of things in both canvases but one of them is updated less often then it might make sense to have multiple canvases. Games do this often for the HUD or status. For example drawing a HUD for an MMORPG showing 100s of items and a chat window. The chat window has 100s or even 1000s of text characters. The items are probably drawn on a frame per item so if that's all we had it could easily be 1200 things to draw. If every item has a name of average 10 characters that would be another 1000 things to draw.

If they don't change often (as in every frame) some games would draw them to a texture (which is what drawing to a canvas is) and then just drawing the texture every frame (1 draw). Of course if you're making a game in the browser you could use the browser itself for your HUD rather than another canvas.

As one data point it's what the browser itself does (or at least both Chrome and Firefox did at one point in time)

You used to be able to display the textures in firefox in 3D. Each of the "layers" shown was effectively an internal canvas that firefox had rendered that portion of the page into with the hope that it doesn't have to render them again. When one part of the page changes only the texture that contains the part that changed needs to be re-rendered after which all the existing textures are recomposited to redraw the page. That's way faster than drawing 1000s of individual characters, borders, backgrounds, etc...

[image]

So the concept has a point but like all the comments mention "it depends".

I made a gamejam game once with a mostly static tiled background. Lets say it was 30x20 tiles that's 600 tiles that need to be drawn. Once drawn the background was mostly static so it made some sense to just draw it once into a canvas and put the characters on a separate canvas above.